# foreach, JSON & PHP

Tags: php, foreach, getjson

I've looked at various answers, and I am assuming it is due to the lack of a foreach loop that I am only receiving one variable. There are 32 categories, with multiple links for each category.

**Table Structure**:

```
CREATE TABLE `cattb` (
  `catNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`catNo`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `linktb` (
  `catId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `URL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  KEY `catId` (`catId`)
)
```

**SQL Query**:

```
SELECT catId, catName, URL, title, description FROM linktb, cattb WHERE linktb.catId=cattb.catNo
```

**PHP**:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $json['categories'][] = array( 
        "catId"=> $row[catId],
        "catName"=> $row[catName],
        'links' => array( 
            "URL"=> $row[URL],
            "title"=> $row[title],
            "description"=> $row[description]
        )
    );
```

**Response:**

```
"categories":[
    {"catId":"1",
    "catName":"Career Resources",
    "links":
        {"URL":"http:\/\/www.designanddesign.com\/jobs.php",
        "title":"Design & Design",
        "description":"World-Wide Job Offers"
        }
    },
    {"catId":"1",
    "catName":"Career Resources",
    "links":
        {"URL":"https:\/\/www.nuans.com\/rts-str\/en\/home-accueil_en.cgi",
        "title":"NUANS Report",
        "description":"Naming A Company (Federal)"
        }
    }
```

**What I want to see:**

```
{   categories: [
    {   catName: "Career Resources",
        catId: "1",
        links: [
            {URL:"http://www.designanddesign.com/jobs.php",title:"Design & Design",description:"World-Wide Job Offers"},
            {URL:"https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/cc/CorporationsCanada/hm.html?locale=en_CA",title:"Corporations Canada",description:"Incorporating a Business"},
            {URL:"http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/",title:"CSS3 Patterns",description:"Patterns to use for backgrounds"},
            {URL:"http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient",title:"CSS Gradients",description:"Cross-browser Compatible"}
            ],
    },
    {   catName: "CSS",
        catId: "2",
        links: [
            {URL:"http://www.designanddesign.com/jobs.php",title:"Design & Design",description:"World-Wide Job Offers"},
            {URL:"https://www.ic.gc.ca/app/scr/cc/CorporationsCanada/hm.html?locale=en_CA",title:"Corporations Canada",description:"Incorporating a Business"},
            {URL:"http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/",title:"CSS3 Patterns",description:"Patterns to use for backgrounds"},
            {URL:"http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient",title:"CSS Gradients",description:"Cross-browser Compatible"}
            ],
    }
```

How would I write the for-each loop for the arrays?

Comment: with your code, `links` will not be an having multiple entries but only one. There's no looping to generate that list like you specified above.

Comment: How do you want to display array of links although you don't have any feed data to it !
see what @phazorRise typed

Comment: So there is no way whatsoever for me to get my links to create a second array with my data?

Comment: If you want to make a list of links in each item you must do a loop in array of links and this can't be achieved unless you store them in the same field in the database , because $row[URL] has 1 URL only not multiple URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of which categories you've seen by indexing them by id. Add to the links array if you've already seen that category. Set $json['categories'] after you are done.

```
$catRows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['catId'];
    $links_entry = array(
        'URL' => $row['URL'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'description' => $row['description']
    );
    if (!isset($catRows[$id])) {
        $catRows[$id] = array(
            'catId' => $id,
            'catName' => $row['catName'],
            'links' => array($links_entry)
        );
    } else {
        $catRows[$id]['links'][] = $links_entry;
    }
}

$json['categories'] = array_values($catRows);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `while` loop you are resetting `$json['categories']` on each iteration.

Try

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $json['categories'][] = array( 
        "catId"=> $row[catId],
        "catName"=> $row[catName],
        'links' => array( 
            "URL"=> $row[URL],
            "title"=> $row[title],
            "description"=> $row[description]
        )
    );
```

Comment: That definitely got me more results! However now the second array still isn't working properly. I've updated my post to my current response from the PHP. All the links belonging to one category should be displayed under that category, and not under a new category with the same name.

Comment: This is because everytime you enter your `while` loop; you will be erasing the content in `$json`  try moving `$jon` out of the loop, then work with pushing items into the array; this will retain the data inside the array before you enter the loop for the second time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to apply an array_push in this situation

Answer (score 0):

To your first problem that is "getting single entry". Use

```
$items = array();   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $json['categories'] = array( 
        "catId"=> $row[catId],
        "catName"=> $row[catName],
        'links' => array( 
            "URL"=> $row[URL],
            "title"=> $row[title],
            "description"=> $row[description]
        )
    );
    $items[] = $json['categories'];
 }
```

Regarding your next problem having single entry in `links` array. There's problem with your current schema. The way I see it now is, you've `catName` and you've got link and stuff about that catName in single table. This is so redundant. You can normalize it further and have separate table say **cat_meta** for url links, title and description and catId that will point out the cat for you.  Next use join while selectin data. This will return array of entires from **cat_meta** that matches with your query. And you use `foreach` and iterate thourgh it to form that `links` array.

Comment: I've added my current table structure, which I believe is what you are suggesting. I'm assuming I should be changing my query to include left/right joins?